# Plotting an interactive time-tracker in Pyqtgraph

Tags: python, animation, pyqtgraph

I am currently working to create an interactive time-tracking line which passes through the curve along X-axis.

**Problem:** I have been able to code that using Animation from Matplotlib, but have been only able to make the line move (i.e., *it is not interactive*).

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import csv_splitter
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.colors as cm
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import os
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = unicode ('C:/FFMPEG/bin/ffmpeg.exe')

with open('C:/Users/j/Desktop/Force.csv','r') as input, open('C:/Users/j/Desktop/Op.csv', 'w') as output:
    try:
        read = csv.reader(input)
        for r in read:
            non_blank = (line for line in input if line.strip())            
            for i in range(17):
                next(read)                
            output.writelines(non_blank)
    finally:
        print("Done!")

data_orig = np.genfromtxt('C:/Users/jkspu/Desktop/Op.csv', dtype =int, delimiter = ",")
fig = plt.figure()
X = data_orig[412:524,1]
Y1 = data_orig[412:524,4]
Y2 = data_orig[412:524,3]
Y3 = data_orig[412:524,2]

plt.plot(X, Y1, 'r--', X, Y2, 'b--', X, Y3, 'g--')
plt.xlabel('Time -----> (ms)')
plt.ylabel('Force Data -----> (N)')

X_MIN = 2055
X_MAX = 2615
Y_MIN = -300
Y_MAX = 1500
X_VALS = range(X_MIN, X_MAX+1);


def update_line(num, line):
    i = X_VALS[num]
    line.set_data( [i, i], [Y_MIN, Y_MAX])
    return line,

l , v = plt.plot(2055, -200, 2615, 1200, linewidth=2, color= 'gold')
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, len(X_VALS), fargs=(l, ), interval=15, blit=True, repeat=False)
print(update_line)

FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer = FFwriter)
plt.show()
```

**Goal:** I would be interested to make the time-tracking line interactive as well as it to move (remain animated). For this purpose, I am trying to use Pyqtgraph (hoping to find an interactive solution).

The code I have used is this (but I don't know how to plug in the matplotlib animation in this code):

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import csv_splitter
import cv2
import os

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

with open('C:/Users/j/Desktop/Force.csv','r') as input, open('C:/Users/j/Desktop/Op.csv', 'w') as output:
    try:
        read = csv.reader(input)
        for r in read:
            non_blank = (line for line in input if line.strip())            
            for i in range(17):
                next(read)                
            output.writelines(non_blank)
    finally:
        print("Done!")

data_orig = np.genfromtxt('C:/Users/j/Desktop/Op.csv', dtype =int, delimiter = ",")

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Plot")
win.resize(1000, 600)
win.setWindowTitle('First_Plot')
p1 = win.addPlot(title="Parametric, grid enabled")
X = data_orig[412:524,1]
Y1 = data_orig[412:524,4]
Y2 = data_orig[412:524,3]
Y3 = data_orig[412:524,2]

p1.plot(X, Y1, pen = 'r')
p1.plot(X, Y2, pen = 'b')
fig = p1.plot(X, Y3, pen = 'g')

p1.setLabel('left', "Y Axis", units = 'N')
p1.setLabel('bottom', "X Axis", units = 'ms')






if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

A picture of how I would ideally be looking forward to:

[image]

**Request:** May I kindly ask some expertise in having an animated line (+ interactive as well) in Pyqtgraph?

I hope I could be clear, if not please kindly let me know, thanks!

Comment: You have to decide if you want to use pyqtgraph or matplotlib. Both is not possible.

Comment: Yes, would like in Pyqtgraph. I haven't been able to find much help online in having an interactive time-tracking line. But for my curiosity, is it possible to do it in Matplotlib? (The inter-activeness I mean).

Comment: I guess both is possible, yes. I would suggest you remove the tag that you don't need here, because this question would not appeal to any audience really. A matplotlib expert might know nothing about pyqtgraph and a pyqtgraph expert might get confused about the matplotlib stuff.

Comment: Thanks, done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to be able to:

1) Add a vertical line that the user can drag. For that, try

```
vline = p1.addLine(x=0, movable=True)
```

2) Draw markers wherever the vertical line intersects your plot curves. You can do this manually by connecting to a signal that is emitted whenever the line moves:

```
def update(line):
    x = line.value()
    # find and plot intersection points

vline.sigPositionChanged.connect(update)
```